# how to extract cookie and x-rap-xsrf-token from datastudio google?

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I have trying to extract `x-rap-xsrf-token` and `cookie` from datastudio for a while now. This values changes every X hours, so, right now I am filling it manually by extracting them from Networks tab in inspect element
[image]

[image: Networks Tab]

Referrer link: https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/9b7783e4-7b55-4840-93bc-3c9469f519c6/page/2UkNB

Url to fetch data: https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/batchedDataV2?appVersion=20220411_00020038

To get the data it is necessary to have `x-rap-xsrf-token` as header in post requests, however I am doing it manually. Can someone help me get it, so I can automate?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue a few days ago, you might need to remove "/u/0" from your post url.

How would I find out? I tried visiting my datastudio.google in Incognito Mode as I want to know the executing sequence without any caches. Then, it redirected me to the website without "/u/0". This will allow you to extract data without x-rap-xsrf-token Token.

```
import requests

url = 'https://datastudio.google.com/batchedDataV2?appVersion=20220411_00020038'
request_body = {} # get this from your chrome inspect
r = requests.post(url,json=request_body)
print(r.text) # Data output
```

PS: The appVersion looks like a "To-Date" type, you can do something like this to make it more robust

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
url = 'https://datastudio.google.com/batchedDataV2?appVersion={}_00020038'.format(today)
```